# Is Database design for social network application correct or should i do some modifications?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am making a social networking application. The database will be MySQL with around 10000. And till now I have come with the following database scheme.

User-details(These two tables when the user registers for first time)

Database Design
User_Table(user_id,username,password);
 Personal Information(*user_id*,dob,sex,contact)

For posting a status(When the user post a status and is updated on other people's wall)
I am thinking of making 4 separate tables for that)

1. For posting the status which have unique id.
2. For storing and retrieving the names of the person who liked the status.
3. For storing
   and retrieving the comments on the status and names of the people
   who commented.
4. For retrieving the likes on comments made on a status.

The database Schema is as follows:
Status_Table(*status_id*,user_id,status,date,time,no_of_likes,profile_pic_id)
Likes_Table(status_id,username)
Comment_Table(status_id,user_id,comment,comment_id,no_of_likes_on_comments)
Likes_on_Comments(comment_id,username)

Follow System  (just like twitter)
 Database Schema
Followers(user_id,followers_id);

Notifications(for likes,comments,tags,follow)
Database Schema
Notification(notification_id,user_id,sender_id,status_id,type,is_seen);

Is this database design best for my application or should i come up with some changes?

Also I am not sure about the photo implementation. Where I should stores the pics of all the users.(The pics include (profile pics,albums)
Is it a good way to store it in database or should I store them in file Systems. and give the path of the photo/album in the database??

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One would think that by now, someone would have designed the definitive social networking database schema, and published it somewhere.

Comment: there is no definitive social networking database schema..it depends from app to app

Comment: please comment if u can really give some answers..

Comment: Google "open source facebook clone" and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Several comments regarding your schema:

1) You should consider merging several table. If two tables that have "one to one" relation and there is a strong connection between the information from one table to another then you should merge the tables.
This will be the case of USER_TABLE and PERSONAL_INFO .

2) Regarding STATUS_TABLE, STATUS_LIKES, COMMENTS and COMMENTS_LIKES - 
I will consider merging all into two tables -

USER_ACTION - will hold and action like comment, picture posting or status change.

LIKES - will hold the likes of the USER_ACTION table.